# Creating enterprise web application using AWS Lambda & API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Can we create an enterprise web application using AWS Lamda? An application like a Client Management application which may have functionalities like below
- managing the customer details and logins
- Invoicing module for customers - generate and updates invoice and notify the customer using email
- Reporting on profit and loss.

If you think this can be attained using AWS API Gateway and AWS Lamda, Can you please let me know the high-level architecture of this system?

NB> I am very new to this AWS world and I am trying to learn its use in a real-world scenario and how to architect it

Comment: You definitely can do that, although you need something as a front-end as well. If you're interested in this, with real-world example, try reading Peter Sbarski - Serverless architectures on AWS. Great book, real-world examples, and he talks about how https://acloud.guru/ was architected using AWS Lambda

Comment: Please watch this video, which builds a serverless web app from scratch using Lambda and API gateway